# How to make a Wordpress URL SEO freindly by rewrite rules

Tags: php, seo, wordpress-theming

Can someone help me to make a WordPress site URL SEO friendly

Currently i have URL like this : https://example.com/pagename/?view=testconsultant

and I want to make it like this: https://example.com/pagename/testconsultant

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how your pages are set up but you should be able to do that directly from the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Actually i have created a table in database and inserting custom values, and i need to show on front-end, everything working fine but i want to remove get parameter, I know its possible by WP rewrite rules, but unfortunately i don't know much about rewrite rules, you can see I'm passing get parameter "view" into query string, i need to rewrite URL without get parameter

Comment: Have you looked at the Admin > Settings > Permalinks section?

Comment: Yes i have selected permalink by "Post name". its working fine for custom post types and pages, category, archive etc.